# How to get details of Jenkins job triggered in "Post-Build Actions" from Jenkins REST API?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-api

I have a Jenkins job A which triggers job B in its Post-Build Actions section.

[Post Build Actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYvv0.png)

Need Jenkins REST API with which I can get build result details for job A which should include details for job B as well.

I have tried this:

```
http://myjenkins/view/all/job/A/1/api/json?pretty=true&tree=actions[triggeredBuilds[number,url,result]]
```

However, this does not include details of job B. Basically this triggeredBuilds action doesn't include details of build triggered in Post-Build Actions.

Answer (score 0):

Found that Jenkins REST API fetches details of sub-project only when the parent project has enabled "Block until the triggered projects finish their builds" check on that sub-project.